# Android - Deleting apps

Tags: android

How can I delete an app in android programmatically without being the device rooted?
It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You cannot uninstall an app directly any more than you can install an app directly.

Android 4.0 (API Level 14) added [`ACTION_PACKAGE_UNINSTALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE), so you can request that the OS uninstall some package, but this will involve user confirmation.

Comment: But i've seen airdroid and then can uninstall an app directly from the web :O

Comment: @MarcOrtiz: No, it does not. It initiates an uninstall, presumably using `ACTION_PACKAGE_UNINSTALL` or some prior undocumented equivalent. The user has to confirm the uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

But why you don' t want to root your device ? It has a lot of advantages, and process of rooting is really simple. On web you can find some applications which will root your device and all you have to do is a simple click